# performance evaluation for a php web project

Tags: php, performance, evaluation, evaluate

How to test my php search engine project ?

1. Client side Minimum browser requirement
2. How faster the website is?
3. performance

Any tool available for that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend ySlow which is a firefox plugin found here:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/ - will give server side recommendations to speed up your site beyond just network speed tests

As well as Googles page speed which is available as a chrome extension:
http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/using_chrome.html - will give server side recommendations to speed up your site beyond just network speed tests

These will answer points 2 & 3

As for point 1:
http://browsershots.org/ will show you a rendered version of your site in any os/browser combo you want

As for your server side PHP code there are many commercial audit services or google for online php optimizations which will bring up articles like:

http://code.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

- Google Chrome can profile your website and offer some basic tips for improving speed alongside a chart showing resource loading times. Hit <kbd>F12</kbd>, click **Network** and reload the page. For an audit, hit **Audits** and click **Run**
- Test your website in different browsers. There aren't a whole lot of them to try out.
- As for "performance", that's a vague term.

Comment: "There aren't a whole lot of them to try out" -> If you factor in a reasonable amount of versions for each this task can be cumbersome to say the least! Added to that os/browser combinations and adding in mobile coupled with the amount of templates/js in your code base cross browser compatibility can take awhile to say the least.

Comment: Start from the bottom up and work your way to the top. If the website works fine in FF 3, then it works fine in the rest of the versions. Chrome is pretty similar in that regard. IE is a pain, but there are only three major versions to test with, so you shouldn't have any problems. FF, Chrome and Opera are pretty consistent across platforms so the only other browser is Safari, which isn't hard to test if you have a Mac.

Comment: Hmmm interesting point, but I still argue (from personal experience as a seasoned senior front architect) that depending on the size of the site or application this can take days or weeks (in a shop with modest QA) depending on the technologies used.

Comment: Also there are times that a project will work fine in say FF10, but not in FF3, although firefox has a fairly decent upgrade engine the biggest culprit by far is IE. Thank god IE6 is at 1% or less market share when you exclude China!

Comment: By the FF analogy I meant work up the version history. Most of the sites I've made work in FF 3.6 with minor tweaks, but that's just personal experience.

Comment: Cool, I on the other hand beleive in writing w3c valid code (HTML5/CSS3) than using CSS/JS fallbacks for unsupported browsers. If everyone developed for FF3 and IE6 the web would not be what it is today, IMHO. Push what is possible!

Comment: Most of the modifications are just overrides for the defaults that aren't present in the older browser versions, so there aren't really any hacks that need to be done. As for W3C, tell that to Microsoft ;)

Comment: I can make any project validate even in IE ;) As for "Most of the modifications are just overrides for the defaults that aren't present in the older browser versions, so there aren't really any hacks that need to be done" - > wow, really? If you say so my 12+ years experience tells a whole different story. There are entire JS libs/CSS libs devoted to this issue, very surprised to see/hear/read any one say something like this, lol

Comment: Validate is one thing, render is another. I code valid HTML5 and CSS3 as well, but IE usually refuses to care. As for "hacks", I meant like `*rules` and other invalid declarations. Usually you have to modify the HTML a little to make things work and break down gracefully for older browsers.

Comment: "Usually you have to modify the HTML a little to make things work and break down gracefully for older browsers." -> Sometimes, and this is what my point was originally, cross browser compatibility can take time. You should also clearly state your goal on what browsers/versions are acceptable. This is where staying on top of browser stats/user stats comes into play. If your doing anything uber cool like border radius, gradients, box/text shadow, rgba/hsla, font-face, etc... these should all have css fall backs for older browsers to be cont.

Comment: so even though it may not look quite as cool, it will still render a pleasant experience for the user. I really like how Paul Irish does it in HTML5 Boilerplate and for JS/CSS3 transition w/ modernizr

Answer (score 0):

1. Test all broswer you can.
2. Use microtime function to calculate how much time it take to load.
3. Goes in 1 and 2.